SAML Authentication with Azure success but AuthenticationManager.SignIn with claims, does not authenticate
We are doing SAML authentication with Azure AD.
The ExternalLoginCallback method gets the external authenticated user, using AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo()
When we check this object's IsAuthenticated property, it shows true. This means that the user is authenticated from Azure AD.
However when we create the Claims and try to login our user (from code) using AuthenticationManager.SignOut() the user is not not authenticated in our system. I verified this from AuthenticationManager.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.
Any one has any Idea why we can face this issue?

Answering to my own question.
It turns out that the AuthenticationManager.SignIn using claims allowed the current user as Authenticated. However on response.redirect to any other page, the user was not authenticated.
This was happening because we were using cookies with SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict. Commenting this did allowed the user to remain logged in even on next requests.
